# Backtracking algorithm | Subset of an Array: how does the array remove the elements?

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

The code below is to find out all of the subsets of a array. This solution is using the backtracking algorithm.However I got a little confused about this solution. When the tempList is [1,2,3] the i = 3, then the call is ended. So the tempList becomes [1,2] and My question is how does the tempLits becomes [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U6zZ.jpg) ? 
I drew a pic about my quesion, the red line is where I got confused. Can anyone help me with this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.(I already debug this code, I still can not solve my problem)

```
public static List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    backtrack(list, new ArrayList<>(), nums, 0);
    return list;
}

private static void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> tempList, int[] nums, int start) {
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
    for (int i = start; i < nums.length; i++) {
        tempList.add(nums[i]);
        backtrack(list, tempList, nums, i + 1);
        tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);` is is what doing the job after returning from a recursive call

Comment: Each recursive call removes one element from the list, but when the recursive call returns, the one above it can then remove another element.

Comment: You should rename the method. This is not backtracking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking. There are no steps that do not lead to a part of the solution. It's simply a recursion.